# Deserialize an XML document with XmlArrayAttribute rows into object correctly using C#

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, deserialization, xml-deserialization

I have an XML that looks like this:

```
<document>
    (...)
    <flex>
        <attrGroupMany name="foodAndBev">
            <row>
                <attr name="agency">ASA EACH CASE36</attr>
                <attrQualMany name="ingredientsList">
                  <value qual="en">IL EACH CASE3688s</value>
                  <value qual="en">IL TEST</value>
                  <value qual="en">IL TEST2</value>
                </attrQualMany>
            </row>
            <row>
                <attr name="agency">ASA EACH CASE36</attr>
                <attrQualMany name="ingredientsList">
                  <value qual="en">IL EACH CASE3688s</value>
                  <value qual="en">IL TEST</value>
                  <value qual="en">IL TEST2</value>
                </attrQualMany>
            </row>
        </attrGroupMany>
        <attr name="FlexType">food</attr>
    </flex>
</document>
```

To deserialize this XML into a class, I created the following structures:

The `Document` class looks like this:

```
public class document
{
        (...)
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order = 158)]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("attr", typeof(AttrRddType), Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable = false)]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("attrMany", typeof(AttrRddManyType), Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable = false)]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("attrQual", typeof(AttrQualRddType), Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable = false)]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("attrQualMany", typeof(AttrQualRddManyType), Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable = false)]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("attrQualOpt", typeof(AttrQualOptRddType), Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable = false)]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("attrQualOptMany", typeof(AttrQualOptRddManyType), Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable = false)]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("attrGroup", typeof(AttrGroupType), Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable = false)]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("attrGroupMany", typeof(AttrGroupManyType), Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable = false)]
        public List<object> flex
        {
            get
            {
                return this._flex;
            }
            set
            {
                this._flex = value;
            }
        }
}
```

`AttrGroupManyType` class looks like:

```
public class AttrGroupManyType
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string name { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayAttribute("row", Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("attr", typeof(AttrRddType), Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable = false)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("attrMany", typeof(AttrRddManyType), Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable = false)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("attrQual", typeof(AttrQualRddType), Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable = false)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("attrQualMany", typeof(AttrQualRddManyType), Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable = false)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("attrQualOpt", typeof(AttrQualOptRddType), Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable = false)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("attrQualOptMany", typeof(AttrQualOptRddManyType), Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable = false)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("attrGroup", typeof(AttrGroupType), Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable = false)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("attrGroupMany", typeof(AttrGroupManyType), Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable = false)]
    public List<object> row { get; set; }
}
```

**UPDATE**

When defining **AttrGroupManyType** this way, I'm able to deserialize / serialize between an XML string and an object of `Document` type, but I cannot get more than one **row** per `attrGroupMany`.

All attributes get merged into **one row**.

For example: foodAndBev, that originally had the following structure:

`[row0] => { agency, ingredientsList }`

`[row1] => { agency, ingredientsList }`

Gets serialized as:

`[row0] => { agency, ingredientsList, agency, ingredientsList }`

Also, if I change the dataType of the `row` property from `List<object>` to `object[]`
I get only the data in the first row, duplicated attributes don't make it into the output xml.

For the example above, I only get:

`[row0] => { agency, ingredientsList }`

**My question is:**

How can I change the class implementations to be able to deserialize / serialize mantaining the original data inside **attrGroupMany** nodes, even when multiple `row`s are present?

Comment: So you deserialize XML that has the proper parent/child relationships into a flat object that does not have correct relationships and you some how want to magically have it serialized back into having relationships?  Do you see whats wrong with this approach?

Comment: @ErikPhilips, actually, deserialization/serialization should work for this type of structure. the problem is that each row should be an XmlArrayAttribute, but I need to somehow create another class to group different attributes in one row, and be able to create multiple rows of attributes. maybe a third class that also is an XmlArrayAttribute

Comment: @ErikPhilips Just edited the question with an example of what I'm trying to do, but doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### First attempt. **XSD** tool

---

I tried to create **C# classes** by typing `xsd /c file.xsd`, since I had the schema of the generated XML, nontheless, this method didn't work because xsd.exe always returned the following error:

> Microsoft (R) Xml Schemas/DataTypes support utility [Microsoft (R)
>   .NET Framework, Version 4.0.30128.1] Copyright (C) Microsoft
>   Corporation. All rights reser
>
> Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException.

However, this method may work for you, considering the case that you may not have crazy "flex" structures like this in your **XSD** schema.

### Second attempt - Paste special (succesfull)

---

Required Visual Studio 2012+

1. Copy content of your XML file to clipboard
2. Add to your solution new, empty class file (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>)
3. Open that file and in menu click `Edit > Paste special > Paste XML As Classes`
   [image]

And that's it!

### The generated classes, after some minor adaptations, look like this:

---

**`Document` class:**

```
public class document
{
    (...)
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public Flex flex
    {
        get
        {
            return this._flex;
        }
        set
        {
            this._flex = value;
        }
    }
}
```

**`AttrGroupManyType` class:**

```
public class AttrGroupManyType
{
    (...)

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("row", typeof(Flex), Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable = false)]
    public List<Flex> row
    {
        get
        {
            return this._row;
        }
        set
        {
            this._row = value;
        }
    }
}
```

**Finally, the new `Flex` class:**

```
public class Flex
{
    public Flex()
    {
        itemsField = new List<object>();
    }

    public Flex(object item) : this()
    {
        itemsField.Add(item);
    }

    private List<object> itemsField;

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("attr", typeof(AttrRddType), Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable = false)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("attrMany", typeof(AttrRddManyType), Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable = false)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("attrQual", typeof(AttrQualRddType), Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable = false)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("attrQualMany", typeof(AttrQualRddManyType), Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable = false)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("attrQualOpt", typeof(AttrQualOptRddType), Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable = false)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("attrQualOptMany", typeof(AttrQualOptRddManyType), Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable = false)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("attrGroup", typeof(AttrGroupType), Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable = false)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("attrGroupMany", typeof(AttrGroupManyType), Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable = false)]
    public List<object> Items
    {
        get
        {
            return this.itemsField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.itemsField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understood your question, but try to have a look on [XmlWriterSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwritersettings(v=vs.110).aspx) and  [XmlReaderSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreadersettings(v=vs.110).aspx) classes on MSDN. There are some properties called Indent and NewLineChars which might help you formatting this.

Comment: Actually I'm trying to change AttrGroupManyType definition to accept more than one "row". Updated my question with an example. Thank you.